# My skeleton css doen't seem to work

Tags: css, skeleton-css-boilerplate

This is the very first time i am trying use skeleton css. Before this I used to use Blueprint css. I am trying a very simple code, but it's not working. Here is my code.

```
<div class="container">
    <section class="two-thirds column" style="border: 1px solid black;">
        2-3
    </section>

    <section class="one-third column">
        1-3
    </section>
</div>
```

It seems that both the sections are taking the entire width of the page. Am I doing something wrong with my code or is my concept wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using http://www.getskeleton.com/

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="nine columns alpha"></div>
  <div class="three columns omega"></div>        
</div>
```

Comment: whats the difference between skeleton and get skeleton @spullen

Comment: get skeleton is the website to get the skeleton css framework. Do you have a link to what you're using?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct.  Are you sure you are linking to all of the stylesheets?  You need to be accessing base.css for the columns to work correctly.